# OpenCL leading with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, opencl, gpu

I'm trying to implement an image processing algorithm using OpenCL, so I think it could be a good idea to work with OpenCV.

I have the following:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.bmp");
width = image.rows;
height = image.cols;

char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(image.data);

cl::Image2D clImage(context,
                        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                        cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8),
                        width,
                        height,
                        0,
                        buffer);

return clImage;
```

But when I run the program it gives me a segfault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was reading the OpenCL Programming Guide source code, and it implements a very similar code which I tested, and it works fine, but it uses freeimage:

```
char *buffer = new char[width * height * 4];
memcpy(buffer, FreeImage_GetBits(image), width * height * 4);

FreeImage_Unload(image);

// Create OpenCL image
cl_image_format clImageFormat;
clImageFormat.image_channel_order = CL_RGBA;
clImageFormat.image_channel_data_type = CL_UNORM_INT8;

cl_int errNum;
cl_mem clImage;
clImage = clCreateImage2D(context,
                        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                        &clImageFormat,
                        width,
                        height,
                        0,
                        buffer,
                        &errNum);
```

So, what's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: My wild guess: your image has actually 3-channels (rgb); you pass CL_RGBA as image format (4-channels), CL computes the wrong dimension for your input data `buffer`, and reads out of bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sbabbi I realized that I could do the following:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv::Mat imageRGBA;

width = image.rows;
height = image.cols;

cv::cvtColor(image, imageRGBA, CV_BGR2RGBA);
char *buffer = reinterpret_cast<char *>(imageRGBA.data);

cl::Image2D clImage(context,
                        CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                        cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8),
                        width,
                        height,
                        0,
                        buffer);

return clImage;
```